# Не добавляются исполненные цели в Яндекс Метрике

Tags: yandex-metrika-api

Добавил на страницу Яндекс Метрику, потом добавил цель, установил плагин, чтобы смотреть, идут запросы или нет, в итоге запросы идут, а на Яндекс Метрике в целях "0".

Мне интересно, почему?

Логи в мазиле для Яндекс Метрики:

15:03:41 счетчик №11111111, загружено 1 целей
15:03:41 счетчик №11111111, отправлено достижение цели типа событие   http://127.0.0.1:8080/freeway/services/
15:03:41 счетчик: №11111111, достигнута цель "888"(№2222222), выполнено условие достижения:   отправка события goal://127.0.0.1/DDD

Вот, он даже получил ответ, как цель называется и что выполнена, но цель как выполненная не пометилась (

Comment: Может, стоит подождать немного?

Comment: Я тоже думал так, но я начал экспериментировать часик назад или больше, статистика по посещаемости обновляется сразу, а цели - не понятно...

Comment: @fromm, мне кажется, что тогда стоит написать запрос специалисту в метрике.

Comment: а это могло быть потому, что я с локально развернутого сайта отправляю..., хотя другая статистика ведь обновляется...

Comment: хз как, но стало отправлять, не знаю в чем была проблема, мб действительно нужно было подождать...

Answer (score 1):

Посмотри настройки счётчика вот тут:

https://beta.metrika.yandex.ru/{counter_id}?tab=filters

Не включены ли какие-нибудь фильтры (Не учитывать мои визиты или Исключить какой-либо трафик)?

Так же во вкладке "Общие" может быть включен чекбокс "Принимать данные только с URL-адресов, указанных в адресе сайта и зеркалах" - его нужно убрать, чтобы события с локального сайта учитывались.